# Merging two IQueryables into a Dictionary with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have an IQueryable and want to stuff that into a Dictionary that has the Foo as the key, and the count of that Foo's Bars collection as the value.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

So the output would look something like this:

```
new Dictionary<Foo, int>
{
    { someFoo, 2 },
    { anotherFoo, 6 },
    ...
}
```

And I need to do this straight from the IQueryable, **without** iterating over the actual objects. To be clear, I do **not** want to do this:

```
// given some IQueryable<Foo> called 'foos' and some Dictionary<Foo, int> called 'dictionary'
foreach (var foo in foos.ToList())
{
    dictionary.Add(foo, foo.Bars.Count());
}
```

**Things I've tried that didn't work**

METHOD 1

```
var dictionary = foos.ToDictionary(key => key, value => foos.Select(foo => foo.Bars.Count));
```

METHOD 2

```
var counts = foos.Select(foo => foo.Bars.Count);

for (var i = 0; i < foos.Count(); i++)
{
      dictionary.Add(foos.ElementAt(i), counts.ElementAt(i));
}
```

Comment: There is no way to avoid enumerating the enumerable if you want to get the count of the collection.

Comment: I'm not clear on your restriction. What do you mean by "not iterating over the actual objects"? `ToDictionary` iterates - you can't build a Dictionary without iteration, it's not a lazy-evaluated object like IQueryable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this would work, have you tried this:

```
var dictionary = foos.ToDictionary(foo => foo, foo => foo.Bars.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this ended up working:

```
var result = from foo in foos
             select new
             {
                 Foo = foo,
                 Count = foo.Bars.Count()
             };
```

That method also has the added benefit of letting my specify the names of the field, which is nice for when I serialize this object to JSON.